# Memory efficiency processing large dataset

Tags: python, loops, memory, large-data

I have a dataset look like this (real data has more columns and millions of rows:

```
data = {'stringID':['AB CD Efdadasfd','RFDS EDSfdsadf dsa','FDSADFDSADFFDSA'],'IDct':[1,2,3]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['Index1'] = [[3],[7,9],[5,6,8]]
data['Index2'] = [[4],[10,13],[8,9,10]]
```

Lists are with dynamic length here, i'm trying to slice string with indexes from lists, the following script works, but it consumes a lot of memory when processing millions rows of data and python doesn't give memory back to the system automatically which is causing issues to run the whole script.

```
data['Output1'] = [x[y[0]:z[0]] for x,y,z in data[['stringID','Index1','Index2']].to_numpy()]
data.loc[data['IDct']>1,'Output2'] = [x[y[1]:z[1]] for x,y,z in data[data['IDct']>1][['stringID','Index1','Index2']].to_numpy()]
data.loc[data['IDct']>2,'Output3'] = [x[y[2]:z[2]] for x,y,z in data[data['IDct']>2][['stringID','Index1','Index2']].to_numpy()]
```

I was trying gc.collect() but didn't work well to free up memory. What would be a memory efficient way to run the same calculation or ways to free up memory back to system after each steps in the script? Please kindly advise, thank you.